# Consulta sqlite cargada en listview

Tags: android

```js
  public ArrayList consultar() {
        ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<>();
        bd = bdPaises.getReadableDatabase();
        String q = "SELECT * FROM Paises";
        Cursor consulta = bd.rawQuery(q, null);
        if (consulta.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                listado.add(consulta.getString(0)+""+consulta.getString(1)+""+consulta.getString(2)+""+consulta.getString(3));

            } while (consulta.moveToNext());

        }


        bd.close();
        return listado;


    }
```

Tabla sqlite con, nombre, capital, continente, habitantes, entonces realizo la consulta y se me cargan todos los datos en el item del listview, lo que quiero es que solo se carge el dato nombre, y al hacer un click en el item que se me abra otra actividad con el resto de los datos.

Comment: Nada más tienes eso?

Comment: Hola bienvenido, agrega lo que intentaste y los problemas que se te presenten, pero una duda tan general es dificil de responder.

Comment: Lo que pretendo hacer es que cogiendo los datos de método consulta pasarlos a un item del listview, los que sucede es que le paso un arraylist y me salen en el item todos los datos, y solo quiero que se pase el primer dato, y al pulsar sobre ese item que se abra otra activity con el resto de los datos de la consulta, es decir por ejemplo si los datos son nombre, capital, continente y habitantes, que en el listview salga solo el nombre en este caso de un país, y al pulsar sobre él, abrir otra acitvity con el resto, capital de ese país, continente y habitantes, perdonad mi igonrancia.